# Solidity - View of BigNumber elements when returning entire array

Tags: getter, dynamic-arrays, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I have a getter function in a smart contract that returns (among other things) a dynamic array of integers. For every element, I get the following line:

> BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [Array] }

As the elements are integers, I would expect to see the actual value after c:, since when returning the same element from a mapping, I would get:

> BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [value] }

where value would be the current value of the uint variable.

Could someone explain to me why this is so, and if its possible to somehow see the value of each element when returning an entire array?

Here is the getter:

```
function getStats(string _name) public view returns(address,string,bytes32[],uint256[],bytes32){

    bytes32 h = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_name));

    require(developers_all[h].namehash == h, "A Developer with that name does not exist");

    return (developers_all[h].owner, developers_all[h].name, developers_all[h].skills, developers_all[h].skill_levels, developers_all[h].namehash);
}
```

As well as the mapping and the struct, the array I am referring to is `skill_levels`

```
struct Developer {

    address owner;
    string name;
    bytes32 namehash;
    bytes32[] skills;
    uint256[] skill_levels;
    uint wallet;
}

mapping (bytes32=>Developer) public developers_all;
```

Comment: Can you share your contract?

Comment: @IftifarTaz I added the parts i think are relevant, if you need more let me know

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/iftifar-taz/developer-truffle-demo) is a demo I prepared for your use case. Unfortunately i can't regenerate your issue. Are you converting your the `BigNumber` response to number using `.toNumber()` or `.toFixed()`?